# some questions about java Scanner

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Grs.png)
}

Why does the code on line 6 have the same effect on line 8? Is there no distinction between the starting point of this while loop?

Comment: The compiler does nothing with line 8 since it is blank.The line is generally ignored. You could have ten or more blank lines and they will all be ignored by the compiler.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think OP wants to know why it seems to not make any difference if the scanner was initialized outside of the `while` in contrast to inside of it. Btw,, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should follow this tips to use the `Scanner` properly:

Mixing any `nextXXX` method with `nextLine` from the `Scanner` class for user input, will not ask you for input again but instead result in an empty line read by `nextLine`.

To prevent this, when reading user input, always only use `nextLine`. If you need an `int`, do
`int value = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`

instead of using `nextInt`.

Assume the following:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your age:");
int age = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter your name:");
String name = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", you are " + age + " years old");
```

When executing this code, you will be asked to enter an age, suppose you enter `20`.
However, the code will not ask you to actually input a name and the output will be:

```java
Hello , you are 20 years old.
```

The reason why is that when you hit the enter button, your actual input is

```java
20\n
```

and not just `20`. A call to `nextInt` will now consume the `20` and leave the newline symbol `\n` in the internal input buffer of `System.in`. The call to `nextLine` will now not lead to a new input, since there is still unread input left in `System.in`. So it will read the `\n`, leading to an empty input.

So every user input is not only a number, but a **full line**. As such, it makes much more sense to also use `nextLine()`, even if reading just an age. The corrected code which works as intended is:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your age:");
// Now nextLine, not nextInt anymore
int age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter your name:");
String name = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", you are " + age + " years old");
```

The `nextXXX` methods, such as `nextInt` can be useful when reading multi-input from a single line. For example when you enter `20 John` in a single line.